# The ordinry fixed -effects analysis of variance in R

Tags: r, anova

I would like to run the ordinary fixed-effect analysis of variance in R. Part of my data set are:

```html
S T E W
1 A 1 1
1 A 2 1
1 A 3 2
2 B 1 1
2 B 2 2
2 B 3 2
3 A 1 1
3 A 2 1
3 A 3 2
4 B 1 1
4 B 2 2
4 B 3 1
```

And I want to get the following table.

```html
Variable df SS MS
W   
T    
E   
S   
W x E   
W x S   
Error   
Total
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you googled around a bit? http://www.personality-project.org/r/r.guide.html#anova See also `car::Anova()`

Comment: Hi Ben- Thank you, I have tried lme4 but I was unsuccessful. Would you Advise me about car::ANOVA, do you mean Car package?

Comment: I mean the `car` package (lowercase).